# The MX record of the FQDN used by an MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, internal-dns

Does the MX record of the fully qualified domain name used as an MX record matter?

For example, let's say that `example.com` has MX records which point to:

```
mx01.example.com
mx02.example.com
```

But `mx01.example.com` and `mx02.example.com` each have their own MX records which point to:

```
mx01.googlemail.com
mx02.googlemail.com
```

The individual A records of `mx01.example.com` and `mx02.example.com` are correct for the sending and receiving of email for `example.com`, but can their own MX records interfere with anything if it's set to something else?

Comment: mx01.example.com and mx02.example.com aren't MX records, they're A records. The fact that they have mx in the name doesn't make them MX records. Your MX records may "point to" these A records, but they are not MX records themselves. An MX record specifies which host or hosts is/are responsible for mail. The MX record "references" or "points to" an A record.

Comment: @joeqwerty Example.com has the MX records which point to the subdomains I've mentioned (mx01* and mx02*). I just chose my words poorly, that's all.

Comment: I misunderstood then. My apologies.

Comment: this sounds like backscatter nightmare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mail system wouldn't do an MX query for `mx01.example.com`, but instead just do an A record query for it,  so this shouldn't interfere.

This sounds like a bad, confusing and error prone idea anyway. Why would you do this?

Comment: Set different MX records pointing elsewhere to your MX hosts.

Comment: It's just a holdover from a previous setup. It's not a design choice. I was just curious.

Comment: Unless someone sent an e-mail to `bobslawblog@mx01.example.com` instead of `bobslawblog@example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

The described configuration literally means the following:

Emails destined for `*@example.com` use servers mx01.example.com and mx02.example.com (resolving their A-records normally).

Emails destined for `*@mx01.example.com` and `*@mx02.example.com` use servers mx01.googlemail.com and mx01.googlemail.com (again, resolving their A-records normally).

This is not a conflicting configuration, but it is very odd.